# Dragging a range of cells does not maintain formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

For some reason there is a section in my Excel sheet where if I highlight a range of cells and drag it to another location, any cells that overlap the original location and the location I am dragging it to will lose all formatting. This happens in a table range, but it does not happen outside of that table or in my other table range in the same sheet. Very confused why it is happening for just that table (or why it's happening at all). Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ook so I can guess at why it happened, but I won't since I'm too lazy to verify it. But the solution that worked for me is as follows:

1. Create custom table style
2. Right click it and select Apply and Clear Formatting

Tada!